# Angular receives String as array?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am toying around with AngularJS and ASP.Net's Web API working together. I have a TestController in the API that's as simple as it gets:

```
public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public String Ping() {
        return "Pong";
    }
}
```

In Chrome I can go to `http://localhost/api/Test/Ping` and fiddler shows a simple `"Pong"` result and the browser shows:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Pong</string>
```

Back in Angular JS, I setup a factory to call the Ping function:

```
app.factory('API', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        Ping: function () {
            var result = $resource('api/Test/Ping', {}, { get: { method: 'GET' }, isArray: false });
            return result.get();
        }
    };
}]);
```

And a super simple controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', 'API', function ($scope, API) {
    $scope.CallTest = function () {
        API.Ping().$promise.then(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

When I click the button that `CallTest` is bound to, it makes the call, the API returns Pong like it should but the return object is not exactly what I would expect. Response is an odd object:

```
{
    0: """,
    1: "P",
    2: "o",
    3: "n",
    4: "g",
    5: """,
    $promise: {...},
    $resolved: true
}
```

I don't receive any errors and everything syntactically is working fine. I was however hoping that `response` would be a string, especially since I set `isArray` to false in my `API` factory. I believe that angular has to return a "Resource" that has a `$promise` and `$resolved` on it so I now understand it may not work that way. Other than making a trivial wrapper in the WebAPI to return a string as a parameter on a Model, are there options available client side so that `response` could contain a normal string instead of this pseudo array? Like maybe `response.data` or something?

EDIT: When I request from the browser, the `Accept` header contains:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

Which results in the XML result above. When Angular requests the same url, the `Accept` header contains:

```
application/json, text/plain, */*
```

Which results in the content of the response simply being `"Pong"`

Comment: Why aren't you just using JSON.net in your web api and returning json or a JObject to angular?

Comment: @Owen I could wrap it in JSON, XML, SOAP, anything, but a simple string should be the easiest thing to parse correctly.

Comment: From what I've found, dumping a literal into $resource turns that literal into a string array. I had this happen when passing a value to $resource to use as a parameter. If the value was not an assigned variable, the string was broken into an array. Assigning a variable with the value of the literal was the quickest way around this for me. Getting data back from my Web API, I only pass JObjects.

Comment: Here is where I posted on the gitHub commit that I discovered this. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f0904cf12e4f01daa2d4fcbb20c762050125ca55#commitcomment-6782877

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in the docs, `$resource` is *a factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources*.

In your case, you are not trying to interact with a proper RESTful data source, thus the behaviour seems strange.

Until you have a proper RESTful data source and while you just want to hit an API endpoint and retrieve a simple response (such as a string), you should be using the **[`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**:

```
$http.get('api/Test/Ping').success(function (data) {...})...
```

E.g.:

```
app.factory('API', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        Ping: function () {
            return $http.get('api/Test/Ping');
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'API', function ($scope, API) {
    $scope.CallTest = function () {
        API.Ping().success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Good point. Ever since I started using $resource, I completely tune out the $http. This is a situation where it would be warranted.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Angular repository [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f0904cf12e4f01daa2d4fcbb20c762050125ca55), String literals are converted to objects when shallowClearAndCopy iterates over keys. In my case, passing a string literal to $resource caused the literal to become an array of characters. The first way I was able to get around this was to assign the literal to a variable and pass the variable through.

```
api.Trip.get(data.token) - Incorrect
api.Trip.get({token: data.token}) - Correct.
```

Seeing as you're coming from the Web API, this would most likely require your response being sent as a JObject or JToken. My Web API returns JObject using Newtonsoft's JSON.net library, and Angular hasn't skipped a beat yet.